# Get weighting of row per group

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the percentage/weighting of a row per group. An example of the dataframe is seen below.

```
Place   District    Count
A       1           12
B       1           13
C       1           34
D       2           56
E       2           1
F       3           23
```

I need to group by the `District` but get a percentage or weighting on the `Count` for each row `Place`. For example, the calculation for `Place` A would be 12/(12+13+34) and B would be 13/(12+13+34).

The expected outcome would be:

```
Place   District    Count   Weighting   
A       1           12      0,203389831
B       1           13      0,220338983
C       1           34      0,576271186
D       2           56      0,98245614
E       2           1       0,01754386
F       3           23      1
```

I am using pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html)

```
df['Weighting'] = df['Count'].div(df.groupby('District')['Count'].transform('sum'))
```

**Output**

```
  Place  District  Count  Weighting
0     A         1     12   0.203390
1     B         1     13   0.220339
2     C         1     34   0.576271
3     D         2     56   0.982456
4     E         2      1   0.017544
5     F         3     23   1.000000
```